# Word - how to uncheck checkboxes?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word

I have 4 checkboxes but we need to restrict selection to just a single one, meaning if you check the first, the other 3 will go unchecked. I know we could use ActiveX radio buttons but we'd prefer to avoid ActiveX if possible, plus with check boxes we have more control over the layout.

I've set the name of the checkbox appropriately to `Check1`:

[image]

And then I've put this very basic script into the Visual Basic section:

`Private Sub Check1_Click()
    Check1.Enabled = True
    Check2.Enabled = False
    Check3.Enabled = False
    Check4.Enabled = False
End Sub`

But unfortunately checking the first box doesn't uncheck the next 3.

[image]

Any ideas please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are Content Controls, as you indicate, then they do not have a CLICK event. Nor can they be identified by VBA by their Title property. The code you show us is for ActiveX controls, which you say you don't want to use...

Working with content control events is not as simple and intuitive as with ActiveX controls. Similar to form fields, Content Controls only have "editing" events that trigger on the user entering and exiting the content control. These events are available in the ThisDocument module, in the Document category.

The same ContentControlOnExit event triggers for ALL content controls in the document, so you need a Select Case or If conditional to query the ContentControl argument in order to know which content control was exited.

In order to address the other checkboxes you need to use the Document.SelectContentControlsByTitle (or ...ByTag) method which returns an array of all content controls with that title (or tag).

If you really want to emulate a "click" event then you need to insert a Custom XML Part in the document with nodes linked to the content controls. When the user changes the state of the control the ContentControlBeforeStoreUpdate event will trigger, letting you take action.

Answer (score 0):

The property you need is `Value`, not `Enabled`.
The purpose of property `Enabled` is to prevent a control from being changed by user.

Additionaly, you need to prevent it from the events cascade. It means that when you change programatically the value of `Check2`, this will trigger `Private Sub Check2_Click()` and so on.

In order to make it work you should change your code like that:

```
Private Sub Check1_Click()
    If Check1.Value Then
        Check1.Value = True
        Check2.Value = False
        Check3.Value = False
        Check4.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

and similarly for the other check boxes.

---

For your purpose **radio buttons** will be better choice. Radio buttons have built-in functionality to uncheck currently selected button if other one is checked.

Comment: Thank you! I've just updated to `.Value` but still get the same problem unfortunately (i.e. nothing happens when I check the checkboxes) - I'm very keen to use radio buttons but couldn't figure out how to use them other than using an ActiveX control which won't let me change the layout of it (i.e. a radio buttons directly to the left) - I'm editing someone else's form and it needs to look the same unfortunately.

Comment: @Nick Do you  have other event handlers that manipulate the checkboxes? Are they initially enabled when you check them? Besides, you need to add a similar handler for each checkbox.

Comment: @Nick I have edited my answer. Your issue was caused by events cascade. I think it is a bug in VBA - you have `Click` events for your checkboxes (not `Change`) and they should not been triggered everytime the value of the control is changed, but unfortunately they are.

Comment: Thanks both, @A.S.H no this is the only code I have: http://i.imgur.com/3ulLc5r.png

Comment: @mielk thank you, unfortunately I'm still not getting anything when I click on the Checkboxes :(

Comment: Downvote: not an answer since the OP specifically states he does not want to use ActiveX controls and the suggestion works only for ActiveX.